# C# Index exception unhandeled

Tags: c#, encryption

So I'm doing this for a school project. Its small program which is encrypting some passwords in both directions and I'm stuck in coding from encrypted back to normal version. It should read 2 by 2 chars of encrypted version, replace them with matching char and return it to string. Cause each char in original pass is replaced by 2 chars in encrypted version, usually `,.`, `..`, or similar.
Here is where I'm stuck and no matter what i do following exception doesn't go away

```
else
{
    string target;
    text = "";
    password = richTextBox2.Text;
    for (int i = 0; i <= password.Length; i += 2)
    {
        target = Convert.ToString(password[i])
            + Convert.ToString(password[i + 1]);
        if (target == ",,")
        {
            text += "a";
        }
    }
    richTextBox3.Text = text;
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to tell you the answer because that helps you nothing. Instead, try to use the debugger to find out where exactly the exception happens and why. Inspect the value of `i` when the exception has happened. Does that value look right? This is an easy problem to solve. If you learn to use the debugger you'll be able to fix all such issues yourself quickly.

Comment: You could also simplify your code by using `Substring` instead of `Convert.ToString()`. For example, your assignment of `target` could be written: `target = password.Substring(i, 2);`

Answer (score 1):

Off by one error. Because you test `i <= password.Length`, you'll enter the loop when `i` is equal to `password.Length`, which will cause an `OutOfBoundsException` when you try `Password[i]` - because strings are 0 based indexed, you should always stop just before this occurs. In this case, change `<=` to `<`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= password.Length - 1; i += 2)
```

**EDIT** I've added a check against `password.Length - 1` because you also access `password[i + 1]`, which will could into the same problem

It might also be helpful to add some checks and ensure `password` has an even number of characters, or you could run into the same issue since you're incrementing by 2.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, it solved my problem
btw password will always have the even number of chars because no matter how long was original password, encrypted one will have 2x more chars and each number x2 gives an even number. so its all fine now

Answer (score 1):

Just to hazard a guess I would think that your for loop advancing 2 characters at a time would be a prime suspect for causing an index exception by going past the end of your string.

The way this is written it might even occur regardless of the password length.  So if your password length is 6 you would check at index 0 & 1, then 2 & 3, then 4 & 5.  At this point the loop says 5 is <= 6 so lets check indexes 6 & 7 as well, but since your password is length 6 your highest index is 5 so you get a "BOOM" - exception due to index out of range.

At the same time if your password length is 5 it would check index pairs 0 & 1, 2 & 3, and then on 4 & 5 you would again blow up because index 5 is too big for a password of length 5 because its highest index would be 4.

I think that might be the cause of your issue.

The key thing to take away is that the password length property counts  1-based while your indexes (and thus your loop counter) is 0-based.  So when the password length is 6, you want to check indexes 0,1,2,3,4, & 5 but your code is written to check indexes 0,1,2,3,4,5, & 6 (at least one too far every time).

I strongly suggest creating a function with the sole purpose of taking in an even length string and then returning the encrypted version of that string. This may just be as simple as fixing your loop comparison to be length-1:

```
string target;
text = "";
password = richTextBox2.Text;
for (int i = 0; i <= password.Length - 1; i += 2)
{
    target = Convert.ToString(password[i]) + Convert.ToString(password[i + 1]);
    if (target == ",,")
    {
        text += "a";
    }
}
richTextBox3.Text = text;
```

In order to make it work for all strings though you will need to come up with a strategy for odd length strings.  You may need to encrypt the first or last character differently, or append a blank character to the front or back of the password, or whatever works for your encryption algorithm.  Just so long as you find a way to take odd-length strings and make them even or allow you to treat them like they are even.

Answer (score 1):

You're encountering an off-by-one error. Indexes are usually zero based, meaning the first item is `[0]`, the second item is `[1]`, and so on. A string of length `10` where you try to access `[10]` will give you an exception, because the last element is actually `[9]`. Therefore, your for condition needs to use `<` instead of `<=`, so that it never exceeds the last element index.

Comment: Furthermore, you might actually want to use `i < password.Length - 1;` since you later do `password[i+1]` which would fail if `i` was already the last element index.